# jQuery change dynamically created element's text

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got two spans with the same id. One is normal and the other one is dynamically created. Btw, I can not change ids, they must be the same.

```
<span id="mySpan">Hello, World 1!</span>
<span id="mySpan">Hello, World 1!</span>
```

I am doing an ajax request and after the result comes, i want to change dynamically created span's text. First one is changing, and i guess i can not reach to the second one.

```
<span id="mySpan">Hello, World 1!</span>
<span id="mySpan">Hello, World 2!</span>
```

I've been trying to do this for an hour, but no luck.

Comment: Can you add a class to the `span`s? Then select them by the `class` and not by the `id`s.

Comment: The other one is dynamically created with the same id. How is that any dynamically created?

Comment: _I can not change ids, they must be the same_ What? -Duplicate `id` attributes are **INVALID** html

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know it's invalid, but the system that we are using is making this, not me. And I can not modify it. Cuz of that i am trying to manipulate the system.

Comment: You can do what you want once it on the client - `.removeAttr('id').addClass('...')` whatever

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yep, it solved my problem when i use class instead of id. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use same `id` multiple times in a DOM. 
DOM considers only first `id` from top if you have defined same `id` more than once.

This is the reason why it is working with first and not with others.

change `id` attribute to `class` and then deal with the class using jquery to change the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can select both spans with the attribute property

```
$('[id="mySpan"]') //selects both elements
```

but isn't a good practice to use the same id for multiple elements..